# Devo usar prepare em Procedures

Tags: php, mysql, procedure

Abaixo tenho um trecho de código adaptado para exemplificar esta pergunta:

```
<?php

$params = [
    ':codUser'     => $_SESSION['data-user']['codigo'],
    ':codCarrinho' => $codCarrinho,
    ':codPremio'   => $codPremio,
    ':quantidade'  => $quantidade,
    ':subtotal'    => $subtotal
];

$query = 'Call addItemCarrinho(:codUser, :codCarrinho, :codPremio, :quantidade, :subtotal)';

$preparedQuery = self::getConn()->prepare($query);
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
    $preparedQuery->bindValue($key, $value);
}

$preparedQuery->execute();
$result = $preparedQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

?>
```

Está é a forma que utilizo atualmente. Mas andei pesquisando e lendo alguns artigos que dizem não ser necessário o uso do `prepare` em Procedures. Mas por receio continuo utilizando. Minha dúvida é se é possível usar `SQL injection` em precedures?

Comment: Por via das dúvidas é melhor você utilizar prepare(). Acredito que seja complicado o sql Injection e depende muito da má implementação da procedure. melhor prevenir.

Comment: Sim! Sempre fico com um pé atrás com isso!

Answer (score 1):

O ideal é você continuar usando o `prepare` para montar suas *procedures*.

Provavelmente, quando foi comentado que procedures não precisariam do uso do prepare, é porque elas utilizam as informações passadas como parametros internamente e isso evitaria o *SQL injection* dentro da execução delas porém, no momento da montagem da mesma, quando vc está escrevendo ela no PHP, possa ser que a pessoa consiga utilizar *SQL injection* na chamada dela